# Receiving spam from myself

Tags: icloud, email, spam

For the last few weeks, I keep getting the same spam message sent by my iCloud account to my iCloud account. I'm not seeing any other weird behavior in my iCloud.

I did change my linked email to a different one and changed my passwords in both several times but I'm still receiving the emails. How do I get them to stop?

Comment: every time you poke your Apple account, it will email you, for security purposes. What email are you getting & is it just once per 'tweak'?

Comment: It's not apple id related e-mail. Subject is "Medicines International Online" and there is a Russian link to "buy cheap meds" which I'm receiving 5-6 times a day

Comment: then it's not 'sent' by your iCloud account & your question needs to be changed to reflect that.

Comment: The sender says **@icloud.com (**@icloud.com) and it matches my personal account.

Comment: There's also the possibility you are part of a botnet - what OS/antivirus/firewall/gateway are you running?

Comment: OS 10.10.1 and not sure about antivirus/firewall/gateway

Comment: change your iCloud/AppleID password, just in case. Read http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2610 & sign out all devices.

Comment: yes, I've changed my id password as well as my attached email password several times. I've also already signed out of all devices and all browser windows and resigned in though the last step I did after receiving the last one so I'll see if that stops it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like jherran & Buscar웃 might be on the right lines, though - spoofed address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to go to Mail.app → View → Message → All Headers and analyze that headers.

If appears any server not related to iCloud, then copy the content of Mail.app → View → Message → Raw Source window and report in [spamcop.net](https://www.spamcop.net).

Comment: How do I know if the server is not related to iCloud?

Comment: They can fake the name in the header but not the originating IP address. You will have to copy it and use the IP address look up online.

Comment: Example in the email header Received: from mta.hulumail.com ([68.232.199.232]) IP search result Host of this IP: [?]:  mta.hulumail.com

Comment: Ok cool. I'm seeing two lines similar to that. One is an apple server but the other is a tktelekom.pl from Warsaw. I've forwarded the email to their abuse@ and I'll report it to spam cop as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this post searching for an answer. Like the original poster, I've been receiving spam that appears to be coming from my email address (icloud). When I clicked on it from my phone, it seemed to be my address. I thought I had been hacked, even though I'd changed my password - a few times. It never occurred to me it could be coming from someplace else. But it was! Here's how I found out...
From my computer, I marked it as "junk". When I went to my junk folder to delete it, it no longer showed it coming from my account. It showed the actual sender. Mystery solved!Thank you, Tetsujin!

Answer (score 0):

Norton (welknown from the PC world) did write this: The good news is no one has hacked into your account. What you’re experiencing is called “Form spoofing,” and it’s a favorite tool in the spam artillery.

Form-spoofing is annoying, but it’s not dangerous. It’s the sender entering your name and address into the From field in their mail program instead of their own. Outlook, for one, makes this a snap. During the setup process, when asked to enter one’s own email address, spammers choose this option.

Since the name of the game for spammers is hiding their tracks and making sure you receive their mail, from-spoofing is natural. By putting your address in the From field, they obscure the true sender and nearly guarantee that your spam filter won’t block their email. - It's like you can write any returnaddress on an envelope before you drop it into a mailbox.

It's getting real annoying, when you block your own emailaddress, you can risk you can't recieve any mail anymore. They think they can force you to buy their shity stuff when you can't prevent their spam anymore... and they demonstrate at the same time, they know nothing about the human mind and about we would never buy anything, when getting pretty annoyed and angry.  Spamcop.net may be the best way to stop this sick minds...