# My Mac is sending spam emails

Tags: macos, mail.app, security, spam

I do not think this is mere spoofing, and I do not think it's exactly like [Receiving spam from myself](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167908/receiving-spam-from-myself)

Here is a diff of a test email I sent to myself(on the left), and the spam email(on the right).

Note that the green boxes are different between the two.  I blocked it out because I'm not sure if there's a security issue in revealing it.

The thing that makes me think it was my mac, is that the "Recieved:" headers are exactly the same with the exact same IP address.

[image: diff]

another note:  The primary purpose of this mac for me is to run a windows instance via parallels.

Any idea what this is?  Malwarebytes for mac didn't find any malware.

**Note:**  I have 2-factor authentication.  I don't think it's a simple matter of guessing my password.

Comment: Have you changed your account password ? (Despite the spam mail saying that "X Mailer" is Apple mail)

Comment: @ankii  My gmail account password?  Not yet

Comment: @ankii  Is there good reason to suspect that my password has been compromised?

Comment: I thought on the lines of this answer:https://security.stackexchange.com/a/131716 but this gives alternatives too: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104746/im-getting-spam-e-mail-from-myself/104749#104749

Comment: @ankii  I don't think simply knowing my password would cover it because I have 2-factor authentication.  It also doesn't explain why it originated from the same IP address as my mac.

Comment: Changing a password is an easy first step in troubleshooting this issue. I just wonder how much of an email header can be spoofed. If you change your email password and it stops then you found your answer. If it doesn't than the answer to my question may be "not that hard at all."

Comment: @SteveChambers `If you change your email password and it stops then you found your answer.`  I don't agree with that assessment.  For instance, I disabled Gmail on my mac.  If it really is a case of something accessing gmail via my mac.  then that would have stopped it too.

Comment: @SteveChambers  Not only that, but This happened over the course of just a few hours yesterday.  After roughly 12:00pm yesterday, It didn't happen again, and I didn't really do anything about it until 9:00am today.  Maybe this particular symptom would not have happened again at all regardless of what I did.